# This Unity Ray Casting sprite is not following my player when the player enters the Ray Cast | Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I have been working on this 2D platformer game were you play as a person who moves left and right, and jumps. I wanted to make this ai that would wake up when the player first enters this triggers which works, but when the Player enters the Raycast, which when entering is supposed to cause the enemy ai to walk up to the player, does not work. the Raycast is a an empty gameobject child of the object of the enemy ai sprite. all I can say is that I think in my code it has to with the Agro being true, which has not worked at all. this code I had copied from a raycasting tutorial is this video(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2VX8uD_xUlM)

this raycast also is also ment to also not make the agro false when there is an object with the layer "Action" in front of it but still does not do anything.

here is the enemy child object image thing([image: Yes the player has a collider with the tag player])

ignore the trigger. like the image says, it works and is not ment to be fixed

and here is the code

```
`using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Presentsaswehear : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    // trigger code ignore
    private Animator Enemtestone;
    public GameObject FirstTrig;
    public static bool Izintyloip;
    private bool Thecheckert;
    // trigger code ignore


    //Enemy part tracking blablablaaaaa
    [SerializeField]
    Transform Player;

    [SerializeField]
    float agroRange;

    [SerializeField]
    Transform castPoint;

    [SerializeField]
    float moveSpeed;

    Rigidbody2D rb2det;

    bool isFacingLeft;

    //true
    private bool isAgro = true;
   
    
    private bool isSearching;

    void Start()
    {
        
        Enemtestone = GetComponent<Animator>();
        //FirstTrig.SetActive(true);
        Izintyloip = false;
        rb2det = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        Thecheckert = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // trigger code ignore
        if (Izintyloip == true) { 
            Enemtestone.SetInteger("Wakeup", 1);
            Thecheckert = true;
        }
        // trigger code ignore
        
        if (CanSeePlayer(agroRange))
        {
            isAgro = true;
            //ChasePlayer(); uuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu

        }
        else
        {
            if (isAgro)
            {
                //isSearching = true;
                
                if(!isSearching)
                {
                    isSearching = true;
                    Invoke("StopChasingPlayer", 5);

                }
            }
            
            
        }
        
        if (isAgro)
        {

            ChasePlayer();

        }
    }

    bool CanSeePlayer(float distance)
    {
        bool val = false;
        float castDist = distance;

        if (isFacingLeft)
        {

            castDist = -distance;


        }


        Vector2 endPos = castPoint.position + Vector3.right * castDist;
        
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Linecast(castPoint.position, endPos, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer("Action"));
        if(hit.collider != null)
        {
            //(hit.collider.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
            if (hit.collider.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
            {
                val = true;

            }
            else
            {
                val = false;
            }


            Debug.DrawLine(castPoint.position, hit.point, Color.yellow);
        }
        else
        {

            Debug.DrawLine(castPoint.position, endPos, Color.blue);

            

        }
        return val;
    }

    void ChasePlayer()
    {

        if(transform.position.x < Player.position.x)
        {

            rb2det.velocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed, 0);
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 180, 0);
            isFacingLeft = false;
        }
        else
        {

            rb2det.velocity = new Vector2(-moveSpeed, 0);

            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
            isFacingLeft = true;
            // if(transform.position.x > player.postion.x)
        }

        Enemtestone.SetBool("GFW", true);
    }
    void StopChasingPlayer()
    {
        isAgro = false;
        rb2det.velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
        isSearching = false;
        Enemtestone.SetBool("GFW", false);
    }
}
`
```

just letting you know, YES the player has a collider with the tag ("Player")
also sorry if I keep repeating things. Its 3 in the morning RN and I need to sleep so goodnight

Answer (score 0):

Your Raycast might not be reaching desired location. Replace Linecast with

```
Physics2D.OverlapCircle
```

Reference:
[https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapCircle.html][1]

Comment: How do I Physics2D.OverlapCircle?